# Convert XML to HTML JS

Tags: javascript, xml

I am a total 0 in JS but I got a task to write a simple function of converting XML to HTML

Example:

```
<Translation code="200" lang="de-en">
<text>Cat</text>
</Translation>
```

'Cat' should be in HTML

XML structure doesn't change but the content of text node does

Yeah I can google couple of hours how to get it or ask here and close the task, appreciate any help

Comment: Do you really need a script to do that or maybe can you use an already existing tool like [this](https://www.freeconvert.com/xml-to-html) one?

Comment: @Coldark no it is used in code

Answer (score -1):

The quickest is using jQuery

```js
const xml = `<Translation code="200" lang="de-en">
<text>Cat</text>
</Translation>`

$("#content").text($(xml).find("text").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```